# How do I return rows with a specific value first?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want my query to return the rows of the table where a column contains a specific value first, and then return the rest of the rows alphabetized.

If I have a table something like this example:

```
 - Table: Users
 - id - name -  city
 - 1    George  Seattle
 - 2    Sam     Miami
 - 3    John    New York
 - 4    Amy     New York
 - 5    Eric    Chicago
 - 6    Nick    New York
```

And using that table I want to my query to return the rows which contain New York first, and then the rest of the rows alphabetized by city. Is this possible to do using only one query?

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer to the second one if you can, as the first one only works for MySQL and not for MSSQL.

Comment: Done. My original question was about MySQL, but the tags did not reflect that anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I came across this this morning in an effort to do something similar for a problem I had. :)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

On SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, and many other database systems, this is what you can use:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN city = 'New York' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, city
```

Comment: That actually works in any SQL database (and is a much cleaner solution than the accepted answer in my opinion)

Comment: Works for me in Oracle.

Comment: How can I add `name` column after `city` ?

Comment: Put `, name` at the end.

Comment: And for what I needed to place 'New York' (or another value) last, simply swap the 1 and 2... ORDER BY CASE WHEN city = 'New York' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, city

Comment: Works for me in MSSQL !

Comment: This syntax is more compact, but not available in all products & versions. ORDER BY IIF(City = 'New York', 1, 2), City

Comment: Works in Postgres too.

Comment: The `ELSE 2` section means that while New York gets the value 1, all the other values get the value 2. ...at least as far as the sort order is concerned.

Answer (score 107):

If your SQL dialect is intelligent enough to treat boolean expressions as having a numeric value, then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Users`
ORDER BY (`city` = 'New York') DESC, `city`
```

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari: No, MSSQL is too stupid to process equivalency tests in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Have you tried running the above query against MSSQL?

Comment: @chaos: the above statement does indeed *not* run with SQL Server, but that's because the syntax is non-standard and only works for MySQL. When using a `CASE` statement (which is standard SQL) SQL Server can very well use an expression in the `ORDER BY` clause. "*too stupid to process equivalency tests*" is simply wrong. If at all it should read: "*does not support MySQL's implicit casting of  boolean `true` to the value `1` (one).*"

Comment: @Esraa_92: Then you don't have a SQL dialect that can handle it and you need Rob Farley's answer.

Comment: For Postgres, this worked for me: `ORDER BY id = 123 DESC, name ASC`

Answer (score 6):

My answer may be old and not required but someone may need different approach,hence posting it here.

I had same requirement implemented this, worked for me.

```
Select * from Users
ORDER BY
(CASE WHEN city = 'New York' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), city
GO
```

PS

this is for **SQL**