# Order an Active Record Relation with a custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have to order an ActiveRecord Relation.

```
Profile.where(id: [1,2,3]).order_user_preferences
```

where records with country_code = 'US' (or a specific string) first.
I've created this self.order_user_preferences, but I can't access the relation object inside the method.
I think "sort_by" converts the ActiveRecord Relation to an array. Do you know how to keep it as an "Active record relation"?

```
class Profile

      def self.order_user_preferences()
    
          # Order by user country
          countries = ['US']
    
          # User-country first
          return relation.sort_by {|p| countries.include?(p.country_code) ? 0 : 1} if countries.size > 0
      end 
  end
```

Expected results

**PROFILE ID | Country code**

1 | US

2 | EU

3 | JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `order` not `sort_by`. Sort by sort on the enumerable object and it is not aware of associations. Read more here: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by

So you will probably end up with something like `Profile.joins(:countries).where(id: [1,2,3], countries: {country_code: "US"}).order("countries.country_code asc")`

This will bring you any profiles where the id is 1 or 2 or 3 and they HAVE an associated country with country. Profiles that do not have an associated country will not be included.

Comment: I need to put profiles with country_code = US first, then other countries'.
It's not a where condition.

Comment: Oh I see. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637983/order-alphabetically-but-with-one-value-at-the-top