# SQL Specify the order of ORDER BY result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have an ORDER BY clause which order a result set of grouped values.

What I would like the ORDER By to do is result in the No KS2 row being at the top.

The values are conditionally populated from three different columns, but the values are from the same set across all three columns.

The values are null, a string of length zero, 1c, 1b, 1a, 2c, 2b, 2a, 3c.... 5a, 6c, 6b, 6a

Currently my ORDER BY clause brings out the values by ordering baased on the left of the value and the right of the values DESC.

And example result set would be:

```
2a
3c
3b
4c
4b
4a
5c
5b
No KS2
```

Here is an example of what I would like:

```
No KS2
2a
3c
3b
4c
4b
4a
5c
5b
```

The code I have currently is here:

```
ORDER BY
LEFT(
CASE Name
    WHEN 'English' THEN
        CASE WHEN [Ks2en]=NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2en]
        END
    WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
        CASE WHEN [Ks2ma]=NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2ma]
        END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN [Ks2av]=NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2av]
        END
    END,1),
RIGHT(
CASE Name
    WHEN 'English' THEN
        CASE WHEN [Ks2en]=NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2en]
        END
    WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
        CASE WHEN [Ks2ma]=NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2ma]
        END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN [Ks2av]=NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
            'No KS2'
        ELSE
            [Ks2av]
        END
    END,1) DESC
```

Comment: so, is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: What does `No KS2` mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250156/how-do-i-return-rows-with-a-specific-value-first -> this should give you some idea

Comment: Apologies guys, got out of the habit of starting with the question rather than where it comes as I write my post. You'd have found it about half way down, but appreciate by then you may have fallen asleep. Amended answer to accommodate.

Comment: @dognose it makes more sense to the end user to see 'No KS2' rather than just an empty row. The values I talk about are grades that students get at the end of their primary school, the curriculum for primary school is known as Key Stage 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your query with its case output inside a subquery, then on the outer query check it so you can order it first (using a constant). This prevents you from having to repeat that messy `CASE` condition in the `ORDER BY` (I presume the same or similar also exists in the `SELECT` list). This doesn't map to your code exactly (particularly since we don't have all of your code), but should give an idea:

```
SELECT Ks2en /* , other columns */
FROM
(
  SELECT Ks2en = CASE WHEN Ks2en = 'x' THEN 'No KS2' ELSE Ks2en END
    /* , other columns */
  FROM ...your query...
) AS x
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Ks2en = 'No KS2' THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END, Ks2en;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/128df/2

Comment: Yes and the GROUP BY.

Comment: @Matt *what* GROUP BY?

Comment: Its not in my example, but I refer to the result set being grouped in the question. I'm happy with your answer, just need a second to try it out.

Answer (score -1):

In your order by, can you do the following?

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN [Ks2ma]=NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN -1 ELSE [Ks2en] END
```

i.e. always force the 'No KS2' to be a value that you know will sort higher than the rest (based on your data set). This only needs to be done in the ORDER BY

Comment: (1) `=NULL` should be `IS NULL`. (2) the -1 will lead to a conversion error, since it will try to convert `Ks2en` to an `INT`. A `CASE` expression must collapse to compatible types according to data type precedence.

Comment: oops - you're right! I just copied his case statement without thinking.