# Incorrect syntax at '='

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250156/how-do-i-return-rows-with-a-specific-value-first).  I have this table:

[image: <code>tab_id</code> is the second column. <code>order_in_tab</code> is the fourth column.]

`tab_id` is the second column.  `order_in_tab` is the fourth column.

I want to order by `tab_id` equal to `2` first, then rest of `tab_id` ascending, then `order_in_tab` ascending.

```
select * 
from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' 
order by (tab_id='2') asc, tab_id asc, order_in_tab asc
```

However, it says `Incorrect syntax at '='.`.  I'm a complete SQL newbie, so I'm not sure what is wrong (or if I'm misunderstanding the linked solution from above).

Comment: sure that this "order by (tab_id='2')" can work? never seen a "="in a order by so far

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `(tab_id='2')`?

Comment: I made the same mistake OP post says, "I want to order by tab_id equal to 2 first, then rest of tab_id ascending, then order_in_tab ascending."

Comment: See my answer @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc, it shows what you missunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the query like this:

```
select * 
from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' 
order by CASE WHEN tab_id='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, tab_id asc, order_in_tab asc
```

Comment: Close... Shouldn't the ASC be DESC since he wants those first? Or just switch the 1 and 0 in the case statement.

Comment: Can you explain the `CASE WHEN tab_id='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC` part in detail?

Comment: This statement represents calculated value. If tab_id='2' then the calculated value is 1, otherwise it's 0. And then the ordering is done based on this calculated value

Comment: I think "order by CASE WHEN tab_id='2' THEN -1 ELSE tab_id END ASC, order_in_tab ASC" is the solution he's asking for.

Comment: @dotnetom Wouldn't 0 be placed before 1 (referring to the `then 1 else 0` part)?  Or does SQL not work that way?

Comment: If ordering is ascending then 0 comes first and then 1, but after @xQbert noticed my mistake I changed the ordering to descending and in this case 1 comes first and then 0

Comment: Essentially what it is doing is providing a calculated column to sort by.  It's sorting in descending order anything with a tab_id of 2 first, then everything else, then the other sort sequences apply.  It's spot on with the update IMO.

Comment: Will this guarantee that case `tab_id='2'` will always be placed top of the list then the rest is order as ascending (not matter the mix of rows)?

Comment: Yes, this will guarantee that items where tab_id=2 will come first, then all other items will come ordered by tab_id and order_in_tab in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a copy & paste error in your query.

```
select * 
from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' 
order by (tab_id='2') asc, tab_id asc, order_in_tab asc
```

You have a logical expression as the first `order by` criteria.

Maybe you meant

```
select * 
from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' and tab_id='2'
order by tab_id asc, order_in_tab asc
```

Comment: I made the same mistake OP post says, "I want to order by tab_id equal to 2 first, then rest of tab_id ascending, then order_in_tab ascending."

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked is right. You just missunderstood the TYPE of the fields. There it has a string field which can be equalized to a string.

So in your case you have to do as this:

```
select * 
 from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' 
order by (tab_id=2) DESC, 
        tab_id asc, order_in_tab asc
```

`(tab_id=2) DESC` will bring the id with 2 first on the results.

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15ffc/2

EDIT:

The OP said that it is using SQL Server. This answer is for MySQL. On SQL SERVER the correct way is using a CASE statement like:

```
select * 
 from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' 
order by (case when tab_id=2 then 0 else 1 end), 
        tab_id, order_in_tab
```

Comment: It's still complaining about he `=` sign

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc So what is your RDBMs ? Mysql, Oracle, Postgre MSSql?

Comment: I'm doing this through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Then you cant do this. Is it a Mysql statement. You should use the answer provided by @dotnetom As sql server does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

In order by you can not specify tab_id=2. You'll have to add another dummy field which will have say 0 for tab_id=2 and 1 otherwise and order by that field first, then by tab_id. Try this way...

```
select mac, tab_id, unit_id, order_in_tab, 
(case when tab_id='2' then 0 else 1 end) as temp
from cam_to_tab_mapping 
where unit_id='90013550' 
order by temp, tab_id, order_in_tab
```

You (can but) don't need to specify asc in the order by clause, it is asc by default if you do not specify anything.

Comment: You can do that. See my answer.