# Yii: Query builder: expression in order

Tags: php, yii, expression, builder

In AC this order works great, but Query builder make quotes wrong, result error

```
$models = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('id, user_id, title, created, modified, lang, forum_id, post_id, status, views, replies, attached')
->from('posts')
->where('post_id = 0')
->order('attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created DESC, created DESC')
->limit(11)
->queryAll();
```

error:

> CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `title`, `created`, `modified`, `lang`, `forum_id`, `post_id`, `status`, `views`, `replies`, `attached`
>   FROM `posts`
>   WHERE post_id = 0
>   ORDER BY `attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created` DESC, `replies` DESC, `created` DESC LIMIT 11

how to fix it?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: 'attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created DESC, created DESC' is not a valid order clause.

Answer (score 3):

Your `where` and `order` should probably read:

```
->where('post_id = 0')
->order('CASE WHEN forum_id =1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, created DESC')
```

Reference: [How do I return rows with a specific value first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250156/how-do-i-return-rows-with-a-specific-value-first)

Comment: I don't need get only post where forum_id = 1, it's just must be first then another posts

Comment: Then why don't you order by `id` first?

Comment: Look: attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created DESC, created DESC
1) "attached AND forun_id = 1 AND created DESC".. means i need first posts which attached and in forum section with id 1 (News & Annoces..) and this posts must be order by "created DESC" (new in top).
2) ..",created DESC" another posts must sort only be created time.

i don't want to sort by id

Comment: As your error states, the error is being caused by the text `ORDER BY attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created DESC, replies DESC, created DESC LIMIT 11`. I've updated the answer with an SQL standard way of specifying your order.

Comment: and again no. my query works fine in AC Find or if remove filter in CDbCommand in ORDER method:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L1066
e.g.: 
public function order($columns)
{
 $this->_query['order']=$columns;
 return $this;
}

Just i don't want to change yii files, but this method automatically insert quote whats destroy string.

Comment: What is AC? And what is the exact query you are trying to run?

Comment: AC - CActiveRecord, query look at topic

Answer (score 0):

You should take order expression in round brackets to avoid checking on column. This must work

```
->order('(attached AND forum_id = 1 AND created) DESC, created DESC')
```