# How to sort the results based on column-name?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, sql-order-by

How to create smart search query depends on column-name?

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| id |   name   | code1 | code2 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| 1  |  jack    | 1     | 1     |
| 2  |  peter   | 1     | 2     |
| 3  |  abel    | 1     | 3     |
| 4  |  brent   | 2     | 1     |
| 5  |  arnold  | 2     | 2     |
| 6  |  chester | 3     | 1     |
| 7  |  morgan  | 3     | 2     |
| 8  |  olin    | 3     | 3     |
| 9  |  marvin  | 3     | 4     |
| 10 |  gavin   | 3     | 5     |
| 11 |  harley  | 4     | 1     |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

Well, I have **3 keywords:** `name`, `code1`, `code2`

My question is about the order of results depends on those keywords. There is some examples:

**Example1:**

```
$q = 'name brent'; // it is what user writes for search in the input
                   // actually I meant of smart is detecting this automatically:
                   // keyword: 'name', value: 'brent'
```

I want this output:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| 4  |  brent   | 2     | 1     |
|                               |
| /* the order of other colunms |
|    does not matter */         |
|                               |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

---

**Example2:**

```
$q = 'code1 3';
```

I want this output:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| 6  |  chester | 3     | 1     |
| 7  |  morgan  | 3     | 2     |
| 8  |  olin    | 3     | 3     |
| 9  |  marvin  | 3     | 4     |
| 10 |  gavin   | 3     | 5     |
|                               |
| /* the order of other colunms |
|    does not matter */         |
|                               |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

---

**Example3:**

```
$q = 'code1 3 code2 2';
```

I want this output:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| 7  |  morgan  | 3     | 2     |
|                               |
| /* the order of other colunms |
|    does not matter */         |
|                               |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

---

**Example4:** If there is all three keywords in input, `code1` and `code2` have higher priority.

```
$q = 'name jack code1 3 code2 1';
```

I want this output:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| 6  |  chester | 3     | 1     |    // code1 3 code2 1
| 1  |  jack    | 1     | 1     |    // name jack
|                               |
| /* the order of other colunms |
|    does not matter */         |
|                               |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

---

**Example5:** If the value of keyword (`name jack` => keyword: `name`, value: `jack`) does not exist, it means: The keyword and its value will not be considered, Just like it does not exist in the input.

```
$q = 'code1 2 code2 5';
```

I want this output:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| 4  |  brent   | 2     | 1     |
| 5  |  arnold  | 2     | 2     |
|                               |
| /* the order of other colunms |
|    does not matter */         |
|                               |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

---

For start, I think I have to separate the numbers of string, something like this:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!u', $q, $matches);
```

And then use them in my query,something like this:

```
... IN (" .implode(',', $matches[0]) . ") ...
```

Or I don't know, is there any good solution? Actually what I need is a magic ordering ...!

Comment: I think you're confusing 'rows' and 'columns'

Comment: Actually I want to know, how can I define some priority for columns? and then order them by those priority ....

Comment: ordery by x = 'foo' DESC - or see FIELD()

Comment: I don't understand how example 3 and 5 are different.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250156/how-do-i-return-rows-with-a-specific-value-first Here is a Fiddle using something along the lines of that answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9514c6/4

Comment: @McAdam331 Really thanks for that fiddle. Also the difference between example3 and 5 is: in the example5 `code2 5` does not exist in table.

Comment: This kind of problem should be tackled in a real programming language, not SQL.