# Trouble with query select distinct order by case

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

I've learned how to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with `ORDER BY` with the help of the question :
[How to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in same SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement)

And I've learned to use `ORDER BY CASE` from this question:
[How do I return rows with a specific value first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250156/how-do-i-return-rows-with-a-specific-value-first)

But I have a query that is hard to write:

I have a table `CUSTOMER` with a column `NAME`, I want to get all the **distinct** names of the customers, and I want to find name 'Hamza' first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "CUSTOMER"."NAME",
    Max("CUSTOMER"."NAME")
FROM "CUSTOMER"
WHERE
    "CUSTOMER".id >= 2
GROUP BY "CUSTOMER"."NAME"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ("CUSTOMER"."NAME" = 'HAMZA' ) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

The **ERROR**:

> ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
>   LINE 15: ORDER BY CASE WHEN ("CUSTOMER"."NAME" = 'HAMZA' ) THEN 1 EL...
>   _________________.^
>   SQL state: 42P10
>   Character: 372

---

**Edit**

It's solved with:

```
SELECT "CUSTOMER"."NAME", -- distinct keyword removed here
    Max("CUSTOMER"."NAME")
FROM "CUSTOMER"
WHERE
    "CUSTOMER".id >= 2
GROUP BY "CUSTOMER"."NAME"
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN ("CUSTOMER"."NAME" = 'HAMZA' ) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
CASE WHEN ("CUSTOMER"."NAME" = 'GIORNO' ) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping will already ensure you get distinct customer names. Just drop this modifier and you should be fine:

```
SELECT "CUSTOMER"."NAME", -- distinct keyword removed here
    Max("CUSTOMER"."NAME")
FROM "CUSTOMER"
WHERE
    "CUSTOMER".id >= 2
GROUP BY "CUSTOMER"."NAME"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ("CUSTOMER"."NAME" = 'HAMZA' ) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get all the distinct names of the customers, and I want to find name 'Hamza' first.

Why not just do this?

```
SELECT "CUSTOMER"."NAME"
FROM "CUSTOMER" 
GROUP BY "CUSTOMER"."NAME" 
ORDER BY ("CUSTOMER"."NAME"  = 'Hamza') DESC
```

Using `SELECT DISTINCT` with aggregation functions usually just confuses the query logic.

I also have no idea why you are selecting the name twice.

Comment: Indeed the solution was not using DISTINCT, but for the rest of the query, it may not make senses, because there was business things, I've changed